# How to reference a table column using cell value?

Tags: excel, cell, vba

I have a table and I want to reference a column using a cell value.
Well, I have this:

```
Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("Table1[[Column1]:[Column3]]").Copy
```

And I am trying to replace the name of the column (header) by a cell value, like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("Table1[[Range("A1")]:Range("A4")]").Copy
```

Please, suppose that I have "Column1" written in cell A1 and "Column3" written in cell A4.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1[[" & Range("A1").Value & "]:[" & Range("A4").Value & "]]").Copy
```

I assumed you had a typo shown in bold

Worksheets("**Sheets1**")

Comment: @CarolinaYumiYida You're welcome! Please take a minute to accept the solution to mark your question as Solved.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was trying to figure it out how to accept the solution.